# Omnisharp is not loading for a Godot Engine Project

Tags: c#, godot, omnisharp

I'm trying to use C# in the Godot engine and Omnisharp is not cooperating. When I load the solution in Visual Studio Code I get the following error:

```
    Target: c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.sln

OmniSharp server started with .NET 6.0.402
.
    Path: c:\Users\riley\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.2-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.39.2-net6.0\OmniSharp.dll
    PID: 18340

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 10.0.19044.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: .NET Core SDK 6.0.402 17.3.2 - "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: .NET Core SDK 6.0.402 17.3.2 - "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\"
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Did not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Did not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses' on host 22092.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621))
 ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)
File name: 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
 ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, String ilPath, String niPath, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.MSBuildLoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at NuGet.Packaging.Signing.PrimarySignature.Decode
   at NuGet.Packaging.Signing.PrimarySignature.Load(Byte[] data)
   at NuGet.Packaging.Signing.PrimarySignature.Load(Stream stream)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageArchiveReader.GetPrimarySignatureAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Packaging.Signing.PackageSignatureVerifier.VerifySignaturesAsync(ISignedPackageReader package, SignedPackageVerifierSettings settings, CancellationToken token, Guid parentId)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageExtractor.VerifyPackageSignatureAsync(String source, Guid parentId, PackageIdentity package, PackageExtractionContext packageExtractionContext, ISignedPackageReader signedPackageReader, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageExtractor.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<InstallFromSourceAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageExtractor.InstallFromSourceAsync(PackageIdentity packageIdentity, IPackageDownloader packageDownloader, VersionFolderPathResolver versionFolderPathResolver, PackageExtractionContext packageExtractionContext, CancellationToken token, Guid parentId)
   at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.InstallPackageAsync(RemoteMatch installItem, NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, PackageExtractionContext packageExtractionContext, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.InstallPackagesAsync(HashSet`1 uniquePackages, IEnumerable`1 graphs, IList`1 downloadDependencyInformations, NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.TryRestoreAsync(LibraryRange projectRange, IEnumerable`1 frameworkRuntimePairs, NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, IReadOnlyList`1 fallbackPackageFolders, RemoteDependencyWalker remoteWalker, RemoteWalkContext context, Boolean forceRuntimeGraphCreation, CancellationToken token, TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity, String telemetryPrefix)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteRestoreAsync(NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, IReadOnlyList`1 fallbackPackageFolders, RemoteWalkContext context, CancellationToken token, TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAsync(RestoreSummaryRequest summaryRequest, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.CompleteTaskAsync(List`1 restoreTasks)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunWithoutCommit(IEnumerable`1 restoreRequests, RestoreArgs restoreContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.NuGetSdkResolver.NuGetAbstraction.GetSdkResult(SdkReference sdk, Object nuGetVersion, SdkResolverContext context, SdkResultFactory factory)
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The SDK 'Godot.NET.Sdk/3.3.0' specified could not be found.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.csproj'.
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Godot.NET.Sdk/3.3.0' specified could not be found.  c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.csproj
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1](IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, T1 arg0)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(IEvaluatorData`4 data, Project project, ProjectRootElement root, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Int32 maxNodeCount, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, ILoggingService loggingService, IItemFactory`2 itemFactory, IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, IDirectoryCacheFactory directoryCacheFactory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 projectConfigurationsInSolution, IList`1 loggers) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 162
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 configurationsInSolution) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 84
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader, Guid sessionId, DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:line 117
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<LoadProject>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 305
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 316
c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.csproj(0,0)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Godot.NET.Sdk/3.3.0' specified could not be found.  c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.csproj
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1](IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, T1 arg0)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(IEvaluatorData`4 data, Project project, ProjectRootElement root, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Int32 maxNodeCount, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, ILoggingService loggingService, IItemFactory`2 itemFactory, IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, IDirectoryCacheFactory directoryCacheFactory)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 projectConfigurationsInSolution, IList`1 loggers) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 162
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 configurationsInSolution) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 84
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader, Guid sessionId, DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:line 117
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<LoadProject>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 305
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 316

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\Glasses.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.OmniSharpWorkspace
        Miscellaneous file: c:\Users\riley\Documents\Glasses\scripts\DnD.cs added to workspace
```

It seems like Omnisharp isn't able to find a built in cryptographic library and the Godot sdk. Why would this be?

I found a thread documenting a similar issue [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/58955) but that was an issue with running Godot scripts at all.

I'm able to write and run scripts just fine but this issue is preventing intellisense from working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. In particular an alternative to Omnisharp would be super helpful. Thanks <3

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal (powershell) in VS code and paste this command:

```
dotnet add package System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs --version 5.0.0
```

Restart VS Code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code I forced Omnisharp to load the .csproj file, *not* the .sln file. I'm not sure why the latter doesn't work but I'm glad I found a workaround.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).